# Need motion equations for falling ball for simulating

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, simulations, free-fall

I am currently M.S student in artificial intelligence(A.I) and working on my thesis on reinforcement learning, which robot should learn by itself how to control a quadcopter.

Long story short, I have come up with a method for such purposes, but before I jump into quadcopter and deal with its non-linear controlling problems - which could take a month to program it, I need to test the method to see if it's really a solution for this kind of problems; so I've defined a simplified version of my problem, such as following:

> **Simplified scenario:**
>
> I have a ball **dropped** at an altitude and the program must learn the **force** it needs to apply on the ball to hold it still in the air at a pre-defined altitude.
>   (i.e if target altitude is higher than the altitude that ball's dropped, it should up-force the ball until it reaches the altitude, otherwise, it should moderately stabilize the ball in the target altitude).

In this scenario it doesn't matter how the force will apply to the ball, i.e there is no rope attached or etc. it just gets applied!

As you can see I am all about computer science and the last time I read something related to physics was 6-7 years ago; so the motion equation of this problem is beyond my specialty, but it seems to me that the defined scenario is a classic physic problem.

#### Question:

1. I need equations to formulate the scenario (falling ball with an external force - besides the gravity) to be able to write it's simulator.
2. What about adding some noise to the problem, like air resistance factor or wind, how would be the equations then.

I would really appreciate if someone help a C.S fellow here. :)

---

P.S: Please let the equations be simple as they could be, I am not quite good at reading complicated physic equations.

Comment: For the second part search control theory. For the first part newton's laws would suffice. Total force is mass times acceleration. Solve for the acceleration and simulate with small time steps.

Answer (score 2):

The basic equations, assuming no air drag($^*$) are as follows.

[image: Falling object.]

At $t=0$ we drop the object from height $H$, we assume its initial speed is zero ($v_0=0$). Only gravity ($mg$) is acting on it.

If the object free falls to height $h_1$, energy conservation then shows us that its speed has now become:

$$v_1=\sqrt{2g(H-h_1)}$$

At height $h_1$ a braking force $F$ kicks in, now the net force acting on the object is:

$$F-mg$$

The **net** force will do work on the object so that at $h_2$ the speed of the object will be zero. The work energy theorem allows us to calculate the force $F$:

$$-(F-mg)(h_2-h_1)=\frac12mv_1^2$$
$$\implies F=mg+\frac{mv_1^2}{2(h_1-h_2)}$$
Reworked:
$$F=mg\Big[1+\frac{(H-h_1)}{(h_1-h_2)}\Big]$$

Acc. Newton (second law), to maintain zero speed the net force acting on the object must now be made zero, so the braking force must be reduced to:

$$F-mg=0$$
$$\implies F=mg$$
Note two things. Firstly the treatment also works if the 'hovering' point is above the dropping point, in that case: $h_2>H$.

Secondly, the treatment also works for $v_0\neq 0$, but in that case the expression for $v_1$ becomes:

$$v_1=\sqrt{v_0^2+2g(H-h_1)}$$

$^*$ Note that taking air drag into account requires differential equations to describe this problem.

---

**Kinematic relationships:**

Note that negative velocity means downward motion and $g=9.81\:\mathrm{m/s^2}$.

*1.During free fall:*
$$v(t)=v_0-gt$$
$$y(t)=H+v_0t-\frac12 gt^2$$
*2.During braking:*
$$v(t)=v_1+[\frac{(H-h_1)}{(h_2-h_1)}\Big]gt$$
$$y(t)=h_1+v_1t+\frac12 [\frac{(H-h_1)}{(h_2-h_1)}\Big]gt^2$$